# JQuery ui bridge failing with error l.option is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, dialog

The website I am working on uses a kind of trick to load and initialise all elements.
The basic idea is the following jQuery snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.plugins = function() {
    $('.plugins', this).each(function() {
      var data, elem, name, value;
      elem = $(this);
      data = elem.data();
      for (name in data) {
        value = data[name];
        if (name in $.fn) {
          elem[name](value);
        }
      }
    });
  };
});
```

With this, I can do the following inside the html document as an example:

```
<div id="dialog-add" class="plugins" data-dialog='{ "autoOpen": false }'>
```

Usually I'll use it with the valitor plugin like this:

```
<form class="plugins" data-valitor="">
```

Pretty cool except I am encountering a very weird bug in jQuery ui 1.8.13.
In firefox 4.0.1 I get an error of "l.option is not a function" when you instiate a dialog.

You can see the problem live here: http://jsbin.com/umafo4/9 (edit: http://jsbin.com/umafo4/9/edit)

I have no idea why it is failing

[Edit]
It seems it has something to do with data-dialog and that the name of the data attribute is the same name as the method and yet it works when I call it outside the scope...